# Android 12 Splash Screen API inconsistent behavior

Tags: android, android-12, android-splashscreen

I am implementing the new Splash Screen API but encountered an inconsistent behavior on it. Sometimes the screen with app icon shows and sometimes it doesn't. There is also a long white screen on the beginning which is visibly annoying (The attached image was just speed up 3x since I cannot upload image file higher than 2mb here, but the white screen was clearly visible for a couple of seconds and Splash API seems to cause frame skip from Choreographer log).

Samsung J1 Android L

[image]

```
class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var keepSplash = true

private lateinit var splashScreen: SplashScreen

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        splashScreen = installSplashScreen().apply {
            // Behaves like observable, used to check if splash screen should be keep or not
            setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                keepSplash
            }
            setOnExitAnimationListener { sp ->
                sp.remove() // Remove splash screen
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

fun fetchData() { 
   //Fetching network data... 
   keepSplash = false
}
```

Showing the AlertDialog seems not working unless I minimize the app and reopen it with `setKeepOnScreenCondition`. It seems to block the UI thread, is there other way to retain the splash but not a blocking UI one? Currently we need to show an AlertDialog if something went wrong but at the same time the splash screen will be retain until the dialog is dismiss.

Comment: Do you do any configuration changes during the startup? I had similar issue, where I updated uiMode, which triggered activity recreation, hence white 'flash'.
Also, I haven't tried to set both listeners at the same time, it feels like they're mutually exclusive. Have you tried to only use `setOnExitAnimationListener` and call to remove splashScreen from `fetchData`?

Comment: @krzysztof I temporary solved my issue, the key to retain the splash icon is implementing `setOnExitAnimationListener` and leave it empty.

Comment: Samsung J1 Android L is Android 5 API level 21 which by doc does not support images immediately from app start (only later after activity start) https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen On API 21-22, The icon isn't displayed until the application starts, only the background is visible.

Comment: @mikep that is weird cause I am actually using Samsung J1 Android L since the first time I used this stubborn API that they introduced. As of now it is working fine on my end now, but there is hot start and cold start that is probably causing my issue above: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue, first if you want to keep the splash icon screen on user screen you need to use both `setKeepOnScreenCondition` and `setOnExitAnimationListener`

```
splashScreen.apply {
            // Behaves like observable, used to check if splash screen should be keep or not
            setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                keepSplash // True to keep the screen, False to remove it
            }
            setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenViewProvider ->
                // Do nothing so the splash screen will remain visible
            }
        }
```

or just

```
splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener {

            // Do nothing so the splash screen will remain visible
            splashScreenViewProvider = it

        }
```

Then just call `splashScreenViewProvider.remove()` later when you are done.

Just remember that `setKeepOnScreenCondition` can be a [UI blocking thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen#setKeepOnScreenCondition(androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.KeepOnScreenCondition)) so if ever you are fetching some data during splash screen and showed an error message via dialog, Toast, or SnackBar it wont work. You need to set `setKeepOnScreenCondition` to false first.

The role of empty `setOnExitAnimationListener` here is not to remove the splash screen even after setting a false condition on `setKeepOnScreenCondition`.

**UPDATED**

It is probably best to just use and empty `setOnExitAnimationListener` if you want to control and extend the Splash Screen. Then save its `splashScreenViewProvider` in a variable and use it later to control or dismiss the screen by calling `remove()`. Documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen#setOnExitAnimationListener(androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.OnExitAnimationListener)).

There might times where the splash logo may not show due to how it works with hot start and cold start. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#how

Note that there still issue when installing and running the app directly using USB debugging in Android Studio where the SplashScreen never showed up and stuck in empty screen which can be problematic when you are using Firebase Test Lab. The issue only happens in SDK 31 and 32.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197906327

Comment: splashScreenViewProvider.remove() does not dismisses screen I think It just resources clean up. What initializes dismissing of animation is animation is setKeepOnScreenCondition.

Comment: @mikep I updated the answer with simplified approach, `remove()` is actually removing the splash screen and you can read the documentation here too https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreenViewProvider#remove()

Answer (score 0):

I am using jetpack compose and it working fine

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

var uiState: MainActivityUiState by mutableStateOf(MainActivityUiState.Loading)

// Update the uiState
lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        viewModel.uiState
            .onEach { uiState = it }
            .collect()
    }
}

// Keep the splash screen on-screen until the UI state is loaded. This condition is
// evaluated each time the app needs to be redrawn so it should be fast to avoid blocking
// the UI.
splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition {
    when (uiState) {
         MainActivityUiState.Loading -> true
        is MainActivityUiState.Success -> false
    }
}

setContent {
    if(uiState is MainActivityUiState.Success){
        MainScreen((uiState as MainActivityUiState.Success).route)
    }

}


@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var preferenceDataStoreHelper: MyPreferenceHelper


    val uiState: StateFlow<MainActivityUiState> = flow<MainActivityUiState>{
       val accessToken= preferenceDataStoreHelper.getPreference(ACCESS_TOKEN,"").first()
        if(accessToken.isEmpty()){
            emit(MainActivityUiState.Success(loginRoute))
        }else{
            emit(MainActivityUiState.Success(homeScreenRoute))
        }

    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        initialValue = MainActivityUiState.Loading,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    )
}

sealed interface MainActivityUiState {
    data object Loading : MainActivityUiState
    data class Success(val route: String) : MainActivityUiState
}
```